# input() error - NameError: name '…' is not defined

Tags: python

I keep getting a NameError on "Math" for some reason.

```
years = 10 
D = 100 


p = 0.075 / 12 
T = years * 12 
S = D * ((math.pow(1 + p, T) - 1) / p)

print("In", years, "years, $", end = "")
print(D, "deposited per month will grow to $", end = "")

SFormatted = "%.2f" % S
print(SFormatted, ".", sep = "")
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using input in that code.

Comment: I'm sorry but how would that look? Like I said I am a complete noob...had a friend help me with most of this ><

Comment: In that case, I suggest asking that friend for help with the code they gave you. Stack Overflow is not a coding or debugging service. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `'import math'` first in your script.

Example

```
>>> math.pow(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined

>>> import math
>>> math.pow(2, 2)
4.0
```

Comment: @diags187 Please don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer to your question. Saying "thanks" in the comments is discouraged in favor of upvoting/accepting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the failure is because there's no `math` variable defined in your code, so you can't use `math.pow`.

However, you don't need to `import math` (but that would also work) because there is a `pow` function in the builtins.

So just change:

```
S = D * ((math.pow(1 + p, T) - 1) / p)
```

to:

```
S = D * ((pow(1 + p, T) - 1) / p)
```

or use the power operator `**`:

```
S = D * (((1 + p) ** T) - 1) / p)
```